# string can not be assigned in a compund statement

Tags: c++, string

I don't really understand why this is happening.

I have some functions which are declared like this:

```
std::string unmaskString(std::string &oValue);
```

In the code I do this:

```
v = unmaskString(line.substr(eq+1));
```

and I get a compile error saying:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
```

When I put this in two separate statements it works:

```
v = line.substr(eq+1);
v = unmaskString(v);
```

The first line returns a string object, not even a reference, so I don't really understand the error.

Changing the function to

```
    std::string unmaskString(std::string oValue);
```

also gives that error.

UPDATE:

Changed maskString to unmaskString as this was a mistake, but the problem still aplies as the masString has the same signature.

Comment: Who cares about `maskString` if your problem is with `unmaskString`?!

Comment: The problem is the same. It's not about a function name it's about the temporary object. It was a typo and is irrelevant because the error message is not "undefined function".

Comment: But you've outwitted yourself. Your proposed fix by changing the parameter to a non-reference does actually work, but because you're careless about which function you're changing, you didn't notice that. In any event, keep the question as short and as pertinent as possible. There's no need for us to know all the other parts of your code that aren't connected to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of:

```
line.substr(eq+1)
```

Is a **temporary** object of type `std::string`. Temporaries are *rvalues*, and lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues.

Notice, that if your `maskString()` function does not need to modify its argument (why would it return an `std::string` otherwise?), there is no reason for it to accept its argument as a reference to non-`const`.

The possible solutions are (in order of preference):

- Let `maskString()` take its input **by value**, so that the input argument will be *copied* if it is an lvalue and *moved* if it is an rvalue:

  ```
  std::string maskString(std::string oValue);
  //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  {
      // Whatever is going on...
      return oValue; // This will be MOVED into the object that stores
                     // the value returned by this function
  }
  ```
- Let `maskString()` take its input by lvalue reference to `const` (this way the initialization of `value` from `oValue` will always result in a copy, even if the argument is a temporary), then copy it into a temporary variable that will be eventually returned and moved from. This would work because lvalue references to `const` *can* bind to rvalues (and therefore to temporaries):

  ```
  std::string maskString(std::string const& oValue);
  //                                 ^^^^^
  {
      std::string value = oValue;

      // Whatever is going on...
      return value; // This will be MOVED into the object that stores
                    // the value returned by this function
  }
  ```
- Do what you did: store the object returned by `substr` in a named object, and pass that object to `unmaskString()`.

Comment: Why isn't taking by rvalue-reference an option here?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Well, taking by rvalue reference *alone* is not an option because rvalue references cannot bind to lvalues. The OP would have to introduce an overload for rvalue references that would basically created a copy of the passed rvalue and forward it to the lvalue reference version of `maskString`. But that is useless work, just take by value and let the compiler do the job

Comment: Note that these rules are not arbitrary, they are there to protect you: if the function accepts a non-const reference, it is assumed that it will modify the argument in a useful way, and if you pass a temporary, that modification will be lost. That is most likely a programmer error.

Comment: @DanielFrey: It is not true that `If they won't apply the NRVO, you need std::move`. If NRVO is not applied, the compiler will move it rather than eliding the call to the move constructor.

Comment: @AndyProwl But what about `std::move`ing the lvalue to `maskString`

Comment: @0x499602D2: The client might not want to `std::move` from its string